# How can I conditionally render my Header above this.props.children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is my app.js where all the routes

```
<Layout>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route exact path="/video" element={<Video />} />]
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
       </Routes>
      </Router>
</Layout>
```

This is my loyout component

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Header />
        </Router>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So I have two questions

1. I could able to use `useNavigate` in `Header` since it was not in the surrounded with the `<Router>` but after using  it is working. So is there any better way of doing this?
2. I need to render  conditionally because I don't want it to be on the login page.

Kindly help!!!

Comment: Move the `Header` component into the same router rendering the routes. Use layout routes to conditionally render UI element with specific routes.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks but I tried it did not work.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly was tried, and didn't work?

Comment: @DrewReese ok this works thanks... but what if I need to remove header from some of the pages after login?

Comment: You would use a layout route to conditionally render the `Header` component with the routes you want it to be rendered with.

Comment: @DrewReese If you can share any link to refer this?

Comment: See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes).